# Error en sqlsrv_fetch_array desde PHP a SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

En una conexión desde PHP a SQL server tengo el siguiente error:

> sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource string given

Este es el código:

```
$server = "SQLSERVER\INSTANCIAALABD";
$conn = array("Database" => "NOMBREDATABASE", "UID" => "NAME", "PWD" => "NAMEPWD");
$con  = sqlsrv_connect($server, $conn);

if($con){   
    echo "conectado";
} else {
    echo "desconectado";
}

$tsql = "select NOMBRE from CIUDAD";
$getciudad = sqlsrv_query($con, $tsql);
if($getciudad = FALSE) die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getciudad, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['NOMBRE'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver tu código, con que nos pongas el error no hay nada que podamos hacer.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por las sugerencias para mejorar la publicación. Allí está el código.

Comment: A cual respuesta te refieres raintrooper y gracias?

Comment: Prueba usando el log que te muestra la pag oficial la url es: http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: Tu  if($getciudad = FALSE) die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));     deberia ser if($getciudad == FALSE) die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors())); por eso el erro.

Comment: Ok! claro, olvidé  ==  pero ahora sale este error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function FormatErrors() in C:\Program Files ...

Comment: El error es al hacer un  ... var_dump($getciudad) ...  obtengo ... bool(false)

Answer (score 1):

Para dar rpta a tu inquietud sigue lo siguiente:

```
        $server = "SQLSERVER\INSTANCIAALABD";
        $conn = array("Database" => "NOMBREDATABASE", "UID" => "NAME", "PWD" => "NAMEPWD");
        $con  = sqlsrv_connect($server, $conn);

    /*
    en lugar de validar solo con un echo 
    de conectado valida con el err sql que te 
    genera el dbms cuando hace cx...


        if($con){   
          //echo "conectado";

        } else {
            echo "desconectado";
        }
    */
    if( $con === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

        $tsql = "select NOMBRE from CIUDAD";

        $getciudad = sqlsrv_query($con, $tsql);
    /*
    En este punto es importante identar para que tu consulta sea legible...
    a la vez que validas que tu consulta retorne diferente a false antes
    de iterar con tu bucle...
        if($getciudad = FALSE) die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
    */

    if( $getciudad === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getciudad, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['NOMBRE'];
            echo "<br/>";
        }
```

Ten en cuenta que los errores que te genere la idea es depurarlos y basado en ello le das una solución ya que puede ser por como armas tu consulta, driver en fin... n cantidad de situaciones, con los errores vas a poder saber que sucede realmente en la lógica de tu script..

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias Jose por tus sugerencias que me han ayudado bastante, ahora es más legible el script. Sigo tu recomendación para hacer seguimiento al error arrojado. que ahora hace explicito el contexto de trabajo.

Comment: revisa porfa en tu logica para no usar formatError() en lugar de ello usa sqlsrv_errors(), de como te muestro en mi rpta para ver si te sigue generando la inconsistencia reportada...